# How to get user to select specific date from Calendar, Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, calendar

Well I have written a program in Python which displays A calendar. However what I want to do is, get the user to select a date from the calendar which I will then print. 
Request some guidance as to how can I accomplish the same

Code snippet as follows:

```
import calendar
from tkinter import *

gui = Tk()
gui.title("Calendar")

def cal():
    y = e1.get()
    m = e2.get()
    cal_x = calendar.month(int(y),int(m),w = 2, l = 1)
    print (cal_x)

    cal_out = Label(gui, text=cal_x, font=('courier', 12, 'bold'), bg='lightblue')
    cal_out.pack(padx=3, pady=10)


label1 = Label(gui, text="Year:")
label1.pack()

e1 = Entry(gui)
e1.pack()

label2 = Label(gui, text="Month:")
label2.pack()

e2 = Entry(gui)
e2.pack()

button = Button(gui, text="Show",command=cal)
button.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service. What _specific_ problem are you having?

Comment: Bryan on execution of the program I am able to display a calendar. However I want to make the user to be able to select a particular date, which I will then print. I'm just asking how do I do that?